# Why can't I place this object into an array?

Tags: php

In PHP, you can normally place an object in an array, like so:

```
class Car{}
$car = new Car();
// This runs without error
$array['vehicle'] = $car;
```

I have a custom MVC framework I've built, and I need the controller to get an ORM object from the model, so it can pass that to the view. So, I initialize my user object:

```
$user = new User(2);
```

Now, I want to put that user object into a `$data` array so it can be passed to the view:

($user->data returns an ORM object)

```
$array['user'] = $user->data;
```

The problem is, after doing this, I receive the following error:

```
 Object of class ORM could not be converted to string
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there something I'm missing?
Thanks for any help in advance.

### Edit: Here's what $user->data refers to, this is from the constructor of `class User`:

```
$this->data = ORM::for_table("users")->find_one($this->user_id);
```

(I'm using [Idiorm](https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm) as an ORM)

Comment: Is $data an array? Or an object that implements ArrayAccess?

Comment: @AlexHowansky: $data doesn't exist until I initialize it there, just like you can run `$array['vehicle']` without error.

Comment: What happens if you do `$test = array(); $test['user'] = $user->data`?

Comment: Also, what happens if you do `$test = $user->data;`?

Comment: NullUserException: That's interesting, it works- but I wonder why it isn't necessary to do that with the `class Car{}` example? Both variables are initialized the same way, why would they work differently with different classes?

Comment: Does it work if you take off the `$test = array();` part? I am guessing it's possible that your `$data` var is something else. Have you tried doing a `var_dump($data)` before assigning that?

Comment: Also, what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: NickiC: fixed, Alex: PHP 5.3.6

Comment: @Archio Forget `$user->data`, what's in `$data` array right before assigning?

Comment: @Archio Is there *any* magic in use? Like magic getters, ArrayAccess, references? Because the behavior seems really strange.

Comment: NullUserException, you should submit your comment as an answer so I can accept it- I found the problem. Previously, `$data` had been initialized *as a string*. When I tried to put an object in it, it balked, because it was a string and not an array capable of having objects. Oops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get an error message like:

```
Object of class ORM could not be converted to string
```

The first question you should ask is, "why does it have to be converted to a string"? An array can take a string just fine, so you can guess that `$data` is actually a string and PHP thinks you want to modify `$data[0]`.

As you've seen, dynamically typed languages can leave befuddled if you aren't careful.
When your variables show suspect behavior, try to see what's actually in them using `var_dump()`.

It's also a good idea to explicitly initialize arrays (eg: `$my_array = array();`) before using them.